# Vue js my data lost after reloading my page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a page reload problem.
When I save on Vscode it works correctly on my html page, but when I refresh the page my data is undefined.
The data in the store works well, however it's just on the view profile that it doesn't work only after reloading my page.
If you have any suggestions, I'm a taker, I don't know what to do anymore.

```
views/Profil:

<div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="form-lastName">Nom :</span>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              aria-label="Username"
              v-model="lastName"
              ref="string"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="form-firstName">Prénom :</span>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              aria-label="Username"
              v-model="firstName"
              ref="string"
            />
          </div>


----------


export default {
  name: "ProfilC",
  data: function () {
    return {
      lastName: "",
      firstName: "",
      selectedFile: "",
    };
  },
  components: {
    NavbarC,
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.lastName = this.$store.state.userInfos.user_lastName;
    this.firstName = this.$store.state.userInfos.user_firstName;


----------
sotre/index.js

const store = createStore({
  state: {
    status: '',
    user: user,
    userInfos: {
      nom: '',
      prenom: '',
      email: '',
      image: '',
    },
    dataArticles: [],
    dataComments: [],
    articleInfos: {
      message: '',
      image: '',
    },
    comments: [],
  },

  mutations: {
    
    userInfos: function (state, userInfos) {
      state.userInfos = userInfos;
    },
},
```

Comment: What do you except at the end? Using HMR while developing, the page is kept loaded, so the data. But on production, refreshing the page will obviously refresh the app from start. It depends from where you take the data: api? localStorage?

Comment: On `reload` app initializes again and data shared via services, stores from the different route/component has been lost. This is how `SPA` works. If you want to retain the data on page load then you have to use HTML storage but that is not a good practice to do.

Comment: I understand but why the data store is ok , and not in my view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your using vuex , did you install vuex persisted-state is saved the data on page reload

Comment: This would solve the problem temporarily, but that package is no longer being actively maintained.

Comment: it works but the package is no longer updated, is there no other alternative?